# VB.net save data codes

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and Mysql, and I came across some codes all over the internet on how to connect and save vb data on mysql database..

This is the first type of codes that I encountered in saving data..

```
Sub saveData()
    Dim mysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim cmDsql As MySqlCommand
    mysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlConn.ConnectionString =   "server=localhost;user=root;password=root;database=dbsample"
    Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        mysqlConn.Open()
        Dim sqlQuery As String
        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbsample.tblsample (clName,clAge,clAddress) values ('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtAge.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "')"
        cmDsql = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, mysqlConn)
        rdr = cmDsql.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        txtName.Clear()
        txtAge.Clear()
        txtAddress.Clear()
        mysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the second one...

```
Sub saveData2()
    Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=root;database=dbsample"
    Dim cmdsql As MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    Dim fName As String = txtName.Text
    Dim fAge As Integer = txtAge.Text
    Dim fAdd As String = txtAddress.Text
    sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbsample.tblsample (clName,clAge,clAddress) VALUES (@clName,@clAge,@clAddress)"
    cmdsql = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, mysqlconn)  
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        With cmdsql.CommandText = sqlQuery
            cmdsql.Connection = mysqlconn
            cmdsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clName", fName)
            cmdsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clAge", fAge)
            cmdsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clAddress", fAge)
            cmdsql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
            txtName.Clear()
            txtAge.Clear()
            txtAddress.Clear()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

These two codes both saves data in mysql database successfully... I just want to know what is the difference between these and what does their format in connecting to database means, can someone please explain these two codes for me.. Please forgive my ignorance :) Thanks in advance...

Comment: The difference is that the first one is vulnerable to SQL injection and therefore super-awful. Don’t build queries from user input.

Comment: Ah I see... Umm.. in the second code I encountered some info in the net to avoid the ".addWithValue" what does that mean and why should it be avoided.. Thanks...

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/. yes. Use the appropriate `SqlDbType` for what you’re inserting. (Also, turn `Option Strict` on for your project.)

Comment: You should wrap your `commection` and `commmand` in `using` blocks. You will save yourself a lot trouble further down the road.

Comment: @Ryan thanks..  Umm sir, please forgive by the way what do you mean earlier when you said to not use queries from user input, what does that mean, if you don't mind can you please show an example to me.. Thanks..

Comment: An example is the the first block of code here. It takes user input (what’s in the textboxes) and puts it into the `INSERT` query. Queries are code that runs on your database server, and it’s bad for security to let users run whatever code they want. When you use parameters for all input to your query, the parameters will never be treated as code. A good rule of thumb is that your query should always be one string literal – no `&` or `+` or `String.Format`, just one query that’s always exactly the same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection might be a helpful read.

Comment: I would also suggest that you look into stored procedures, and have mysql run the queries instead serverside. This way if you have changes to the query you won't have to possibly recompile. Also don't forget to accept or upvote an answer that has helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first syntax executes SQL  *directly* to mysql via the string literal:

`INSERT INTO dbsample.tblsample (clName,clAge,clAddress) values ('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtAge.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "')"`

a user with knowledge of mysql can mess with this via your user interface (txtName.Text) and *inject* his own mysql syntax.. possibly a `delete` or worse.

The second one, *Parameterized Queries*, is better as it attempts to prevent SQL injection attacks like that for you without you having to write your own functions to prevent sql injection attacks

ultimately, I would suggest you look into how to make use of [mySQL's stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html). As there are a lot of advantages of using stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

The first option is an example of inline query which can be vulnerable to sql injection, but the same can be avoided by using commandparameter which is used in second one.